# retrieve numeric(10,2) data type from postgresql to Java.Math.BigDecimal in Java. SUM() function Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, hibernate-mapping

I have a numeric(10,2) data type column named "Value" in a Payment table in postgresql Database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PAYMENT(
    PAYMENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('payment_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
    DATE TIMESTAMP,
    PLACE VARCHAR(255),
    VALUE NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
    UTILISATEUR_ID BIGINT REFERENCES UTILISATEUR
);
```

I want to retrieve that numeric value by a BigDecimal Data Type in Java. (dto)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public interface UserSumByGroup {
    public String getFullName();
    public BigDecimal getSumOfValues();
}
```

For some reason all the times the return values for the dto is null when I  execute in the controller..

```
...
List<UserSumByGroup> usersGroupSumPaymnt = userRepo.userGroupSumPaymt();
model.addAttribute("userGroupListSumPaymt", usersGroupSumPaymnt);
System.out.println("usersGroupSumPaymnt=> "+usersGroupSumPaymnt.get(0).getSumOfValues());
...
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT usr.FULL_NAME as fullName, SUM(VALUE) as paymentCount 
FROM PAYMENT pym left join UTILISATEUR usr ON usr.utilisateur_id = pym.utilisateur_id 
WHERE MONTH(pym.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
AND YEAR(pym.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
AND pym.utilisateur_id IN (1,5) 
GROUP BY pym.utilisateur_id, usr.FULL_NAME;
```

Console Log:

```
usersGroupSumPaymnt=> null
```

Do you have some idea why I got always a Null?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To correspond the names of the variables between Spring JPA and the Database, the names of the attributes of the dto object must be the same to the name of the result field in the query.

The name of the result query "paymentCount" needs to be the same as the dto instance "sumOfValues".

So, Change:

```
SUM(VALUE) as paymentCount
```

By

```
SUM(VALUE) as sumOfValues
```